# Can you access the photos you take with the camera?

Tags: far-cry-3

I was just wondering if you could view the photos you take with the camera?

Comment: its not a duplicate but i did see this so i was wondering if you could see the photos that you took since i've took loads

Comment: that questions asking why its there im asking if you can view them its not a duplicate

Comment: A friend of mine showed me the pictures he took of the strip level and the prostitute sign in Bad Town but it was on the X-Box. He says it is under photos but I can't find it. He does have all the DLCs so maybe you can see them with one of the DLCs. If not he has done Xbox violating mods where you can't get achievements if you do that. so you could do it with a mod if you can't find a mod for it it's in the DLCs.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot access the pictures you take with the camera.

Comment: How about print screen, fraps, or any other 3th party program for recording a screen. If there is no screenshot functionality within a game.

Comment: When downvoting answers, writing a comment would be much appreciated.

Comment: @MennoGouw This question is tagged [tag:xbox-360]. Now, are you sure you want to ask about 3rd party programs in this case?

Comment: Just realized this was X-box so my previous comment is rather stupid. However you can run the video signal through a PC and record it in the way i mentioned.

Comment: @Nolonar unless the camera is a 360-exclusive item, answers should address all platforms.